# Spring Annotation driven configuration - Could not resolve matching constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was using spring boot 1.5.3.RELEASE version now I need to move to 2.0.3.RELEASE. The project was working fine in 1.5.3.RELEASE. When I try to deploy my war in tomcat I am getting  the following error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userPartnerDao': Could not resolve to match
> constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple
> parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

I am using annotation-driven configuration and I have no constructor in my class and I am not using any constructor to instantiate objects anywhere in my project. The answers I found are for XML configuration. In my application class, I am including packages in @ComponentScan and @EntityScan. Any ideas?

My class :

```
package com.test.dao.h2;

import com.test.domain.UserPartner;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface UserPartnerDao extends JpaRepository<UserPartner, Long> {
    @Query("select u from UserPartner u  where u.userAccessToken =?1")
    UserPartner findByToken(String accessToken);

    UserPartner findByGivenId(String givenId);
    
    @Query("select u.userAccessSecret from UserPartner u  where u.userAccessToken =?1")
    String getUserAccessSecret(String accessToken);
    
}
```

the class i am trying using userPartnerDao :

```
@Component
public class UserAccessTokenDao
{

    @Autowired
    UserPartnerDao userPartnerDao;

 
    public void doingStuffMethod(String token, String secret, String userId, String userName)
    {
        // doing stuff

    }

}
```

Comment: Try @Repository annotation on UserPartnerDao

Comment: sadly this is not working i have tried to add @Repository annotation and @EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.dao.h2") in my application class, this is weird.